# In Magento 1.9.1, is it possible to make out of stock swatch options for configurable products show, but not selectable?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, color-swatches, swatches

I am using CE 1.9.1 with a custom theme based on rwd.  I have configurableswatches set for Color and Size attributes.  Everything is working fine, except when a configuration is out of stock, the swatch no longer displays.  This is confusing for my customers because the More Views image still shows for the unavailable option.  They also cannot request to be notified when the specific option is back in stock.

Example:
  A product has multiple colors: Blue, Green, & Red, and sizes: S, M, L
  Blue is still available in S & M 
  Green is available in S
  Red is sold out in all sizes

What displays:

Blue Swatch with S  M

Green Swatch with S  M (as strikethru & OOS)

What I want to display:

Blue Swatch with S  M  L (as strikethru & OOS)

Green Swatch with S  M (as strikethru & OOS) L (as strikethru & OOS)

Red Swatch S (as strikethru & OOS) M (as strikethru & OOS) L (as strikethru & OOS)

Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this?  I do show out of stock products.  Can out of stock attributes also be shown?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16285/magento-easy-way-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product-greyed-out.  Check this anwser

Comment: Thanks!  I actually added Amasty's Custom Stock Status extension and was able to do it using an option in the module.