# Magento add label + show out of stock products in configurable product dropdown

Tags: configurable-product, stock, out-of-stock

there are some related messages but not precisely this.

Is there an easy method to
- show both instock/outofstock products (for a configurable product)
- add a label "in stock", "out of stock"

So a drop down with

- S
- M
- L

becomes

- S        In stock
- M        Sold out
- L        In stock

Where one would like to play a little with the label color/css ....

Help appreciated

[image]

Comment: your magento version ?

Comment: Please follow link: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16285/magento-easy-way-to-show-out-of-stock-in-configurable-product-greyed-out